# ./src/index.js Line 36: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am running map function but not getting result due to this

```
    return (
        <div>
         <ul>
         {items.map((item)=>{
             return
             <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>
         })}
         </ul>
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: `conole.log(items)` ? is it an array ? did you check ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to keep your `return` statement and the code it returns on the same line:

```
return (
  <div>
    <ul>
      {items.map(item => {
        return <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>; // this should be one line
      })}
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```

Otherwise [automatic semicolon insertion](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/08/26/javascript-semi-colon-insertion/) will put a semicolon after your `return` and as a result the `map` will return an array of `undefined` values.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this, see if it works

```
return ( < div> < ul> {items.map
(item=>  < li key={item.id}>{item.name}
 < /li> )} </ ul> </ div> )
```

And be sure you have an array in your items 
Hope it works for you

Update : it was buggy and editor hidden my < li > tag, so I put space before li